# I need to make a connection between two devices, who can help me?

Tags: code, model

During the Corona era, it's not always easy to keep distance from each other. However, you still have to stay a metre and a half away from each other.

This is why I want to create a device that hangs on a keycord. This device measures the distance to another device. So it creates awareness, and lets you know when somebody is too close to you.

Does anybody know how to make this connection? I have thought of:

- Bluetooth
- RFID (but only works with short distances)
- GPS (too inaccurate)
- NFC
- Arduino ultrasonic/HC-SR04 (measures only one way)
- BTLE, Bluetooth Low Energy

This is for a school project that will be marketed if it proves to be successful. I'd love to hear from you guys!

[image: my idea]

Comment: Identical questions have been appearing here lately. Those can have the answers for your question already. Did you search for them?

Comment: You're not the first to come up with this idea. You're not the first to ask about distance measuring using <whatever>. Go search this site for "measure distance" and see what you get. The issues are discussed there.

Comment: Well I did find how to measure distance from an object/person etc. But I wasn't able to find how to make a device measure distance from another device. So, if there are like twenty devices, they have to respond to eachother, IF within 1,5 metres from eachother.

Comment: Like any other "how do I measure distance with {wireless communications standard XYZ}", the answer is: it doesn't work.

Comment: You gadget assumes **everyone** has a gadget.  If you have one and I don't, then your gadget would tell you that you are safe - even while I'm standing on your toes and exhaling virus laden air right in your face.  I don't see how that helps anybody.

Comment: @JRE I understand what you say. In the Netherlands, for example, 80 people are allowed to enter a supermarket. Now they give everyone a basket, you deliver it back in after you are done. I want to use that keycord instead of a basket, so everyone has a device like that.

Comment: @IceWhiteWood as explained in my answer, unless all them carry their basket far above their head, so that all baskets can see each other across the different supermarket rows, this won't work.

Comment: Just get a 3 meter diameter [hula hoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hula_hoop)  Hang it on a pair of [men's pants suspenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspenders) so it creates a circle around you.  People will avoid you.  Problem solved.

Comment: @JRE hahah nice one!

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I know. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Some stores in Germany require you to take a shopping cart into the store with you.  The idea being that maneuvering the cart will force you (to some extent) to keep a distance from other shoppers.  Some stores now have a"greeter" who keeps track of how many people are in the store, and keep that number below some safe limit (depending on size of the store.)  They also enforce the mask rule (and sell you a mask for cheap if you need one.)

Comment: Nice @JRE we have the shopping cart also in some shops. We don't have masks in the Netherlands. Unfortunately, I can't go to Kaufland anymore. Because I used to get there twice a month.

Comment: @JRE ah, I think the main reason for shopping carts is that you can avoid the counting greeter by simply limiting the number of carts available

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, they do the same with baskets. They only give out 80, or 50. Depends on the m2 of the store. If they are out of baskets, there are no people allowed.

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Maybe.  I hadn't thought of that angle.

Comment: you don't need a hula hoop ... just wear a tin foil hat ... people will avoid you

Answer (score 3):

A wireless device can only know how far it is from another by somehow measuring the time a signal takes to travel the distance.

Signal strength won't work, because human flesh is much better at absorbing wavelengths that work at this device size than a couple meters of air.

So, if you're between your transmitter and your neighbor's receiver, this won't work at all: the dominant path of propagation would be through reflections on the environment, and they will always be longer than the direct path.

So, in, short: that problem can only be solved by gluing a mast to everyone's hat so that all antennas are at the same height, have a direct line of sight to all other antennas, and then you'll "only" have to solve the many-party proximity sensing problem RF engineering companies have tried to solve for the last ~60 years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcus. I can work further with this :)

Comment: @IceWhiteWood I'm not quite sure how I'd work forward with this (other than dropping the project); distance sensing in dense multipath networks is a very complex problem, and in most cases, one that mathematically can be proven to not have one unique solution that's right.

Comment: I'm still in the draft phase. I can start thinking of a different idea now, because I've been told this doesn't work. It's a school project, you have to deliver two ideas every week.

Comment: @IceWhiteWood:  You can still deliver this idea for your project.  Describe it and how you wanted it to work.  Then, describe why it won't work.  Engineers have to do that all the time.  Some non-technical person has an idea, and an engineer gets tasked to evaluate it.  The engineer then has to provide a clear explanation for why the idea won't work (rolling on the floor, laughing you ass off does **not** suffice as a report on feasability.)

Comment: @JRE how many times do we get asked about perpetual motion machines...

Comment: Thank you @JRE I didn't know it worked like that. I will do that :)

Comment: @JRE I'd recommend working on the high-tier tech support end of things, once in a while! "Hi, I'm this high-ranking engineering officer at this large transnational research institution, and I think I can solve the basic restriction of your devices that they can't send more than 1 Gb/s over Gigabit ethernet link by doing time-sharing on that medium!" didn't only happen to me once, the same guy had the same idea 3 times, each time with months in between

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  Well, of course you're going to laugh your ass off (with the phone muted.)

Comment: @JRE everything's done via email, that has the very big advantage of actually requiring users to formalize a problem statement (which probably solves a lot of things).

Comment: @IceWhiteWood he, by the way, from the category of things that might work: give each basket a beacon. Position a synchronized receiver every meter or so on the shelves. Pick the three to N strongest receivers for every single beacon, and try to estimate the beacons position, and then compute the distance between beacons based on a map of the shop in a computer.

Comment: Thanks! @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 2):

To put some practical details to Marcus's answer, if this is for a practical project, you could get hold of a couple of keyfob style [transmitters and a receiver, at the same frequency (commonly 433.92 MHz)](https://www.laser.com/dhouston/modules.html).

Make sure the receiver has an RSSI (received signal strength) output you can connect a voltmeter or DMM to (i.e. read its datasheet before buying!)

This lets you conduct feasibility experiments, like

1. One transmitter, one receiver, free space. How does the RSSI voltage vary with distance from the transmitter
2. Human body. Does a human body getting in the way affect RSSI voltage (at a fixed 2m distance?) Whoever's wearing the TX or carrying the TX basket stands on the spot and turns around. Do you lose the "neaby person" indication?
3. Does the genius mast on a tinfoil hat (ground plane) solve the human body problem?
4. What happens when you introduce another transmitter nearby?
5. Practical considerations : how long did the TX and RX batteries last?

Simply doing these experiments, or similar, as well as you can, and writing them reporting the results with a conclusion about feasibility using signal strength, would go beyond most school (and many undergraduate university) projects.

As this question comes up a lot, you might report your conclusions here in an answer, with a link to your project report.

You could also point out that using signal travel time involves much more complex (and power hungry) electronics, putting it outside the scope of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!